# Add a new org - certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to add a new org called Org4 in the fabric network generated by the script byfn. I'm following this tutorial http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update_tutorial.html

But I met an error when I try to do the "peer channel update" :

> could not create channel Application sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org4.example.com"

I don't know why the certificate is not valid because I generated it the same way I did and succeed with Org3. Using cryptogen and I changed the config files by replacing 'Org3' to 'Org4'.

First I thought it was because I had already three orgs, but then I create a new network and try to add Org4. It didn't work, but if i try again to add Org3 it will work. So I'm confused about how just changing the name of the Org can impact the process.

Best Regards